# Does "ne" need to accompany "rien"

Tags: grammaire, négation

If I say, "je sais rien," does that express "I know nothing" in a satisfactory way?

Or do I need to say, "je **ne** sais rien."?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you write a French text, then make sure to use *je **ne** sais rien* as much as possible, because in fact, *je sais rien* is incorrect. In spoken language, it's not really a problem to use *je sais rien*.

Same for *ne ... pas*, *ne ... plus* and *ne ... jamais*

Answer (score 3):

Yes, while saying (spoken French) **ne** may be quite often omitted. So to answer your question yes it is satisfactory.

Answer (score 1):

Ce n'est pas l'usage, mais "je sais rien" devrait être considéré comme correct étymologiquement et signifier "je sais une chose".

On dit bien : "je sais quelques riens"

En effet, "rien" vient du Latin *res* = chose.